# Plot Average Values in R Based on Column Headings

Tags: r

Ok this should be easy but I can NOT figure it out. I have data that is called avePrice (using diamond information in ggplot2):

```
Fair      Good Very Good   Premium     Ideal 
282.0    3050.5    2648.0    3181.0    1809.0
```

I want to plot, using the headings (the first row) on the x-axis as labels and the values (second row) on the y-axis.

This seems it should be easy in R but I cannot seem to figure it out!

I can do this

```
qplot(x=c("Fair", "Good", "Very Good", "Premium",  "Ideal"), y=avePrice, geom="bar", xlab="Diamond Cut", ylab="Average Price")
```

which works, but it would seem there HAS to be a simple way to do this without typing in the xlabels manually? Hopefully?

Thanks in advance... I'm expecting to feel dumb when someone points out how :)

Clarification: I know I can move the x=c("Fair...") stuff out of the qplot command and have it elsewhere, but I still am having to manually enter it at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly plot this using `ggplot2` without having to calculate the average prices by cut. Here is a one-liner

```
qplot(cut, price, data = diamonds, stat = 'summary', fun.y = 'mean')
```

Comment: hm, this is far better than what I was doing :-)

Comment: ggplot2 is amazingly flexible with handling data and plots. glad to be of help.

Comment: `stat` is now deprecated?

Answer (score 2):

`ggplot` generally wants data in columns of the data frame.

```
df <- data.frame(Fair=282.0, Good=3050.5, Very.Good=2648.0, Premium=3181.0, Ideal=1809.0)

df.fix <- data.frame(grades=names(df), avePrice=t(df), row.names=NULL)

qplot(grades, avePrice, data=df.fix, geom='bar', stat='identity')
```

But in one line:

```
qplot(x=names(df), y=t(df), geom='bar', stat='identity')
```

Comment: But that doesn't solve my main problem - I don't want to have to type in the column names manually (you are simply moving that step from the plot command to a dataframe creation).

Comment: if you `dput` your data or show me its structure, I can help more.  Otherwise, I have to make data somehow.  It wasn't meant as a work around, only to create some sample data to work with.

Comment: It seems using "names(avePrice)" will do what I am trying - someone posted it as a comment, then deleted it?

Comment: Yes, that should work nicely and is what I was trying to illustrate in my examples.